Tshark grep specific fields
I'm using tshark to decode on the fly the SMPP protocol, e.g.:
tshark -i any -V -Y smpp

This will show, in real time, every single SMPP packet, e.g.
Short Message Peer to Peer, Command: Submit_sm, Seq: 8475778, Len: 215
    Length: 215
    Operation: Submit_sm (0x00000004)
    Sequence #: 8475778
    Service type: (Default)
    Type of number (originator): Alphanumeric (0x05)
    Numbering plan indicator (originator): Unknown (0x00)
    Originator address: \123\110\123\123\123aaa\123
    Type of number (recipient): Unknown (0x00)
    Numbering plan indicator (recipient): ISDN (E163/E164) (0x01)
    Recipient address: 44123456789
    .... ..00 = Messaging mode: Default SMSC mode (0x00)
    ..00 00.. = Message type: Default message type (0x00)
    00.. .... = GSM features: No specific features selected (0x00)
    Protocol id.: 0x43

Is there a way to grep specific fields and output only these?
I tried with:
tshark -i any -V -Y smpp | grep 'Operation|Type of number|Numbering plan indicator|Recipient address'

But it doesn't work. I tried also with:
tshark -i any -V -Y smpp -T fields -e 'smpp.dest_addr_ton' -e 'smpp.destination_addr'

But this will output only the value and I would like to output something like;
Type of number (recipient): Unknown (0x00)
Numbering plan indicator (recipient): ISDN (E163/E164) (0x01)
Recipient address: 44123456789

Could someone advice? Thank you, Lucas

To use alterations (|) in a regular expression, you must enable extended regular expression support for grep as this is not a feature of basic regular expressions.  You do this by using grep with its -E option:
grep -E 'Operation|Type of number|Numbering plan indicator|Recipient address'

Alternatively, you may use several separate basic expressions, each provided via -e (I'm also using -F here as all expressions are plain strings, not actual regular expressions):
grep -F -e Operation -e 'Type of number' -e 'Numbering plan indicator' -e 'Recipient address'


Oh damn! I already used -e (lowercase), that's why it didn't worked! :)
Thank you, it was so simple!!!

Do you think is possible to output also a specific text portion? e.g. from "Length" to "Protocol id". So show all content from a specific string to another string.

@LucasRey sed '/Length/,/Protocol id/!d' or sed -n '/Length/,/Protocol id/p'.  The first deletes all lines not in the specified range while the second only prints the lines in the specified range (the end effect is the same).

Thank you very much, Kusalananda.
